# ImageView size of the launch of the activity

Tags: java, android, imageview

I would like to find the size of an `ImageView` from the start of my application.

For my app, I want to do the same thing as Google Maps, ie display an image, and place pointers to places on this image. Pointers are recovered through the XML files containing `X%` and `Y%` in relation to the image.

To place the pointers on my image, I would do something like this:

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);

    // more code...

    float maxX = imageViewCarte.getWidth();
    maxY imageViewCarte.getHeight float = ();
}
```

The problem is that these values ​​are `null` at the start of the application. So, I tried to do the same in `onStart()` and `onResume()` but to no avail, I get always `0`! However, if I do the same thing in an event like `onClick()`, it returns a real value correctly.

Is there any way that I can get this size when the application starts up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this method to your activity,

```
@Override 
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{ 
     super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
     Log.i("Height",imageViewCarte.getWidth ()+""); 
}
```

During the onCreate you view is inflated but not yet drawn. So this method here gets called after the drawing process and hence you will be able to achieve your target by overriding this method..